# Change an image from img when hovering list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I change the picture from a `<img>` when I hovering an `<li>`, like seen in e-commerces?

What I want is: when I hover a list item, I want the image from another div to change and have the image I hovered (pretty sure I couldn't express myself right)

My html is this:

```
<div id="small-pics">
    <ul>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola1.jpg" class="small-pic">
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola2.jpg" class="small-pic">
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola3.jpg" class="small-pic">
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola4.jpg" class="small-pic">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="img/bussola1.jpg" id="large-pic">
</div>
```

I tried by using the following code, but didn't work:

```
$('.small-pic-li').hover(function () {
    $('#large-pic').attr(function () {
        $(this).attr("src");
    });
});
```

---

## Solved

### It worked by using:

```
$('.small-pic-li').hover(function () {
    var imgSrc = $(this).children().attr('src');
    $('#large-pic').attr('src', imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: gavgrif's answer is right, here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/xpvt214o/905766/

Comment: This does not work because your `$(this)` is ref to `#large-pic`, so you can `var self = this` before and use `$(self)` inside

Comment: IT WORKED (kinda)!
I just had to change `var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');` to `var imgSrc = $(this).children().attr('src');` so by hovering the li I could get the img source.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd also recommend that you look into the jquery mouseenter event https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/#mouseenter-handler instead of using hover -- hover triggers when you enter *and* leave an element.  mouseenter should only trigger once (just a small performance boost)

Answer (score 4):

You have to get the src attribute of the image when hovering over the li and then apply that as the src attribute of the large image.

Since I don't have the images you have - I have added an alt attribute to the images and applied the same change to the alt attrribute of the large image - so that you can see that when hovering over the lis. the alt attribute (and also src attribute) changes for the large image.

```js
  
  $('.small-pic-li').hover(function () {
       var imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
       $('#large-pic').attr('src', imgSrc).attr('alt', imgSrc)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="small-pics">
    <ul>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola1.jpg" class="small-pic" alt="img/bussola1.jpg" >
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola2.jpg" class="small-pic" alt="img/bussola2.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola3.jpg" class="small-pic" alt="img/bussola3.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="small-pic-li">
            <img src="img/bussola4.jpg" class="small-pic" alt="img/bussola4.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="img/bussola1.jpg" id="large-pic" alt="img/bussola1.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple fix for solution for your problem. I've included some random images off Google for demonstration.

```js
$(".small-pic-li img").hover(function(){

    $("#large-pic").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

})
```

```css
.small-pic-li{
    display: inline;
}

.small-pic-li img{
    width: 100px;
}

#large-pic{
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0293/9277/products/05-10-18_Studio_1VD5673_Red_0213_1000x.JPG?v=1529565465" id="large-pic">
    </div>

    <div id="small-pics">
        <ul>
            <li class="small-pic-li">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0293/9277/products/05-10-18_Studio_1VD5673_Red_0213_1000x.JPG?v=1529565465" class="small-pic">
            </li>
            <li class="small-pic-li">
                <img src="https://www.vipboutique.co.uk/images/sasha-hot-pink-cut-out-maxi-dress-p58-477_image.jpg">
            </li>
            <li class="small-pic-li">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0004/6602/6559/products/product-image-452654874_580x.jpg?v=1524259536">
            </li>
            <li class="small-pic-li">
                <img src="https://www.lulus.com/images/product/w_560/1314234_204794.jpg">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The src of the selected small image has been placed as the src of the large image.

Also make sure you include jQuery in the head section.

I would not recommend you have a separate class called "small-pic" since "small-pic-li" can be used to select the image instead, to make the code simplier.

Also note that the "small-pic-li" has been displayed inline to prevent the images from stacking over each other due to the block nature of list elements.

Hope it helps!